# vlc-2.0.4 installation error(lua)

Tags: vlc

i upgraded ubuntu 10.0 to 12.04,install vlc2.0.3 via software center,but HD videos not plays perfectly..so i downloaded VLC-2.0.4 & installed through below command,but gives lua error,

```
 trendwise@Trendwise:~/Downloads/vlc-2.0.4$./configure
 checking for LUA... no
 configure: WARNING: No package 'lua5.1' found, trying lua >= 5.1 instead
 checking for LUA... no
 configure: WARNING: No package 'lua' found, trying manual detection instead
 checking lua.h usability... no
 checking lua.h presence... no
 checking for lua.h... no
 checking lauxlib.h usability... no
 checking lauxlib.h presence... no
 checking for lauxlib.h... no
 checking lualib.h usability... no
 checking lualib.h presence... no
 checking for lualib.h... no
 checking for luaL_newstate in -llua5.1 ... no
 checking for luaL_newstate in -llua51 ... no
 checking for luaL_newstate in -llua ... no
 configure: error: Could not find lua. Lua is needed for some interfaces (rc, telnet, http) as well as many other custom scripts. Use --disable-lua to ignore this error.
```

i installed liblualib50,liblua5.1.0,liblua5.2.0, but again gives error,
which packages should i install ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way you can install the vlc via ppa

Open a terminal and run following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: i am getting this error:--->

W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A6804EA8EAE0D85C

what does that means ?

Comment: Run this command without quote "sudo apt-key adv --recv-key --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com A6804EA8EAE0D85C"  and retry it

Comment: ,i got installed vlc,but when i am running HD video,it not playing well,only audio running.But same video when i am opening in other player(e.g. UMPlayer),it plays well.